# Пространства между Item на expandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Использую ExpandableListView и для пространства между айтемами написал

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="10dp"
```

Это как бы помогло но проблема в том, что когда раскрываю этот айтем то есть дочерние элементы когда раскрываются, то вместо пустого пространства "Серый цвет" будто транспарент поменялся на серый...

Вопрос: Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `ExpandableListView` помимо

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
```

есть еще и

```
android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
```